# How to share common reference among spiders?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I need to read a config file from which to load non-scrapy related configuration properties that I need for the spiders and use that configuration from all spiders I have.

The simplest solution would be to use the settings.py file, but I think this is not the purpose of this file and I would like to separate the scrapy module configuration from my config file.

I have a class that already reads and loads my configuration from a config file, but I dont want to import this module from each spider since I want the configuration to be loaded only once and to be shared among spiders.

What would be the cleanest approach to implement this? should I override the SpiderLoader class in some manner?

Answer (score 2):

The most common way in Scrapy to add non-production settings, is to add a `local_settings.py` file and then add this to your `settings.py` file:

```
try:
    from local_settings import *
except ImportError:
    pass
```

Comment: I think that will do. But I also need to make a query to a DB previous to running all spiders since they use information from that query to operate. How about this?

Comment: `local_settings.py` is still a python file, so things can be executed inside